# Cannot see jwPlayer Video, because of parent white background

Tags: html, css, jwplayer

I have a container of pages and on a particular page I have embedded a jwPlayer video. The problem is that when I fill the div's background color, the video is washed out by the set color.

```
#Pages div { padding:20px; background-color:#fff; border:1px solid #aaa; }



<div id="Pages">

    <div id="Page-1">
        <h2>Page 1</h2>
        <p>This is the first Page.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio. Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra non, semper suscipit, posuere a, pede.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="Page-2">
        <h2>Page 2 - Video</h2>

        <div id="videoWrapper">
            <video id="media"></video>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

What I have tried to change was wrap the video (id=media), into a div and set its own background color. This works and the color is seen which does not wash out the video, but the first Page color still washes it out. What can i try?

Comment: There does not appear to be any use of JW Player on that page. You do not embed JW Player by using a <video> tag.

Answer (score 1):

I tried lots of CSS changes, but I found that just by changing my css from

```
#Pages div { padding:20px; background-color:#fff; border:1px solid #aaa; }
```

to

```
#Pages { padding:20px; background-color:#fff; border:1px solid #aaa; }
```

fixed this problem.